# CRM 2011 SSRS Report on appointments in date range

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to generate a report similar to the system "Account Summary" report. I want to be able to run the report and enter in a date range and the report will return all appointments in that date range with 1 appointment per page. The idea here is a summary report of the client that the appointment is with. So each page of the report would be on one appointment and list account info, opportunity info, case info, etc. I've started with just pulling appointment information first within a date range. Which works but I cannot get the reports to split each appointment onto it's own page (similar to the Account summary report).

Here is my Query text:

SELECT top 10 CRMAF_FilteredAppointment.subject, CRMAF_FilteredAppointment.regardingobjectidname, CRMAF_FilteredAppointment.scheduledstart, CRMAF_FilteredAppointment.location, CRMAF_FilteredAppointment.activityid
FROM            FilteredAppointment AS CRMAF_FilteredAppointment
WHERE        (scheduledstart BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)

Then I just have a table with the values selected. So when the report runs there ideally would be 10 pages each page with 1 row of data in the table for each appointment. Instead the report runs and returns all 10 appointments in the 1 table with 10 rows.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would edit the properties of the "Details" Row Group for the Table.  On the Page Breaks page, I would check the option for "Between each instance of a group".

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure this out. I used a list with a sub report and did the page breaks you mentioned.